# Disable Checkbox with querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, checkbox, selectors-api

I am having trouble disabling checkbox after it has been clicked.  The checkbox has been appended via queryselectorall with a classname.  I was able to use a conditional statement where if any of the checkboxes were clicked it would console-log something, but I cannot get the checkbox to be disabled.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
        let checkbox = document.querySelectorAll('.boxes')

        checkbox.forEach(box => {
            box.addEventListener('change', ()=> {
                if (box.checked = true) {
                        box.disabled = true;
                    }
```

Comment: `box.checked = true` is assigning, not comparing. Change to just `if (box.checked)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, change your if condition from

```
if (box.checked = true)
```

to

```
if (box.checked == true)
```

Because, if you use one = meaning, you are assigning a value.
If you want to do a comparison, use ==.
if you want to compare with the data type, use ===